# change the gridview cell text on bind and roll back the text on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am trying to design a gridview with linkbuttons.

Below is gridview that I want it to be, ID, Name and Status are Label, Click1 and Click 2 are LinkButtons

```
ID ------------- Name ------------- Status ------------- Click1-----Click2 

1 -------------- Name1 ------------ Active ------------ Lnk1--------Lnk2

2 -------------- Name2 ------------ In-active --------- Lnk11-------Lnk22
```

what i am trying is to change the LinkButton cell text(Lnk1 to 'View') on gridview bind. and on likbutton click i want the text as same on gridview bind(i.e Lnk1) and the same with second linkButton..

thank you....

Comment: you can use jquery to bind the onclick event and change your text.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

**Mark Up**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
                        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        runat="server">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Id"
                                SortExpression="id" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
              LinkButton lbtn =  (LinkButton) e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
                lbtn.Text = "View";
            }
        }

        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          LinkButton  lbtnClick = sender as LinkButton;
            lbtnClick.Text = "lnk1";
        }
```

Comment: if the thext "lnk1" is from a datatable of database .. then??@Srinu A

Comment: @htiru lbtnClick.Text = datatable.Rows[rowindex][colindex].ToString(), both `indexes` are integers